# Is there an easy way instantiate many different objects on the fly based on an input without if statements?

Tags: python

I'm creating some simulation software and I'm putting all the initial conditions in a `yaml` file to be parsed.

The thing is, there are many different types of objects to model in the simulation, and I only need to model a few in any one run of the simulation.

My first approach was a long, ugly string of `if else` statements which instantiate and import objects based on the initial conditions. I then replaced that with some still very ugly `eval` and `exec` statements.  My question is, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe show your yaml file and the ways you tried already. Perhaps a factory pattern might be a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps a dictionary?

```
simulation_objects= {
    'bird': bird.Bird,
    'water': water.Water,
    ...
```

I mean those would point to classes, so then to instantiate something for a configuration you'd do:

```
obtype = simulation_objects[confvar] #get the class/type from the dict
ob = obtype() #instansiates (is e.g. bird.Bird()) 
simulation.add(ob)
```

To instantiate the appropriate types of simulation objects based on the configuration, without a lot of if-else statements. Dictionaries are kind of the replacement for switch-case statements of c in python. And is kind of nice functional style I figure, a mapping of params to functions (or well classes here but their constructors anyhow).

I've done this kind of thing often for games and have really liked how classes (and of course functions too) are objects in python so that you can have them in dicts etc.